# How can I integrate the "Offer to save passwords" option of chrome in my own extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've seen its possible for extensions like Microsoft Autofill to override the "Offer to save passwords" setting in Google Chrome as shown in the picture below.

[image: Screenshot of "Offer to save passwords" option in Google Chrome]

I would like to integrate this in my own extension, but unfortunately I didn't manage to find any information / documentation about this.

Does anybody know how this works or has any examples?

Thank you very much

Comment: It uses chrome.privacy.services API, see the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint posted by @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom is correct.
Refer to https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/privacy/ for information about this